# Meteor + Famous-Views, how to create swipe navigations?

Tags: meteor, famous-engine

Using Meteor and Famous together (and Famous-Views), how can I create a swappable navigation/route? I want to go to a new page when I swipe left/right but I want that to be done by way of "swipe-in" effect.

Are there any examples of this somewhere?